# Creating a file in a directory other than root using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am currently working on an auto grading script for a class project. It has to be able to search any number of given directories lets say
for example

usr/autograder/jdoe/

jdoe contains two files house.c and readme.txt.

I need to create a file in jdoe called jdoe.pdf

Currently i'm using this line of code below to get the path to where i need to create the file. Where $1 is user input of the path containing the projects the auto grader will grade.

```
find $1 -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c "dirname {}"
```

When I try adding /somename.pdf to the end of this statement I get readme.txt/somename.pdf

along with another -exec to get the name for the file.

```
\; -exec sh -c "dirname {} xargs -n 1 basename" \;
```

I'm having problems combining these two into one working statement.
I'm new to unix programming and would appreciate any advice or help even if it means re-writing the code using different unix tools.

The main question here is how do I create files in a path other than the directory I call my script from. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just trying to use the `find` command to generate the paths to all the `somename.pdf` files? Or are you trying to do more here?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I'm trying to use find to find the path and create a file named somename.pdf in each path. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
find  "$1" -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'd=$(dirname "$1"); touch $d"/"$(basename "$d").pdf' - {} \;
```

Comment: Awsome! this is what I was trying to do earlier some of my syntax was off. The only thing is the name of the pdf currently from your code is one directory off. I added back in my second portion of code "dirname {} | xargs -n 1 basename" and it's exactly what I needed! thanks so much!

Comment: Expanding `{}` inside the argument to `sh -c`/`bash -c` is *very* unsafe. `find` cannot quote it correctly for that usage. You need to pass it as an argument to the script and use positional parameters for this to be safe `bash -c 'd=$(dirname "$1"); ...' - {}`

Answer (score 2):

You can create files in another path using change directory command (cd).

If you start your script in usr/autograder/script and want to change to usr/autograder/jdoe you can change directory with shell command `cd ../jdoe` (relative) or `cd usr/autograder/jdoe` (absolute).

Now you are in the directory of usr/autograder/jdoe and you are able to create files in this directory, for example `gedit readme.txt` will open gedit and creates the file in usr/autograder/jdoe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply michi. Your reply makes sense. I would need to do absolute because I am hopping between different directories due to multiple students. I do have a follow up question though. How can i pipe the information from my "sh -c dirname" portion of code to cd? I've been confused on how to use the data I get there.

Comment: If you want to combine two statements you can use "&&". For example: you are in your homedirectory (~) and you want to change to desktop and open a file with gedit you can use: "cd Desktop/ && gedit readme.txt" Now you don't need to write "gedit Desktop/readme.txt" because you changed in directory Desktop. This command will change directory and open gedit in one step.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to loop over the files returned by `find` and then do whatever you need to do.

For example:

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
    dir=$(dirname "$filename")

    # create pdf file
    touch "$dir/${dir##*/}.pdf"
done
```

(Note the use of `find -print0` to correctly handle filenames containing whitespace and newline characters.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function process_file { 
    dir=$(dirname "$1")
    name=$(basename "$1")
    echo name is $name and dir is $dir; 
    cd "$dir"
    touch "${dir##*/}.pdf" # or anything else
}

# export the function, so that it is known in the child processes
export -f process_file 

find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c "process_file '{}'" \;
```